# Why does this code use both `document.body` and `document.documentElement`?

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so I'm trying to figure out how this JS code works.. Could you explain me some things?

There's the code (I've copied some of the w3schools' code, full: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_to_top

```
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<script>
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>
```

I think that document.documentElement means it is a HTML and it contains all elements on the page. Am I wrong?

So why we need two variable setting in topFunction()? When I remove this line:

```
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
```

everything still working, so why we need this part of code? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement please read some documentation, it wants to be read

Answer (score 5):

From the question title pre-edit:

> What's the difference between `document.body` and `document.documentElement`?

`document.body` is the `body` element. `document.documentElement` is (in HTML documents) the `html` element.

> So why we need two variable setting in topFunction()?

Because unfortunately, when scrolling the content of the main window, some browsers have historically scrolled `html`, and others `body`. You can try your current browser here:

```js
var n, div;
for (n = 1; n <= 100; ++n) {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = String(n);
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
var bodyDisplay = document.getElementById("body-display");
var docElDisplay = document.getElementById("docel-display");

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  bodyDisplay.innerHTML = String(document.body.scrollTop);
  docElDisplay.innerHTML = String(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
});
```

```css
.top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div>
    body scrollTop:
    <span id="body-display"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    documentElement scrollTop:
    <span id="docel-display"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Scroll up and down</div>
```