# Parent-child relationship between html, head and body elements?

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I was wondering if `<html>` element is the children of "document" object and `<head>` and `<body>` elements are the children of `<html>`, how is this possible that we can access `body` element through document object directly?

Isn't supposed to be `document.documentElement.body` ?

Instead, it allows us to skip the `<html>` root element which is hierarchically the parent of both `<head>` and `<body>` elements.

I am not an expert on HTML and I just wanted to clear up the confusion. I'd appreciate if someone could explain.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit different as you described. Here someone else asked something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49014076/why-does-this-code-use-both-document-body-and-document-documentelement

Comment: document.documentElement returns <html> element, which is the root of <head> and <body>.

Comment: I read that post but it explains something else. I am tryring to understand how can we access the body element right after the document object? while there is a direct descendant of html element (tag)? I thought dot notation only allows access to direct decendants of elements, am I wrong? Seems like body and head are grandchildren of document object and yet we can access them as direct descendant (children) little confused!